# aggregating by sum according the sequence condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Say, here my data

```
     mydat=structure(list(ItemRelation = c(11629L, 11629L, 11629L, 11629L, 
11629L, 11629L, 11629L, 11629L, 11629L, 11629L, 11629L, 11629L, 
11629L, 11629L, 11629L, 11629L, 11629L, 11629L, 11629L, 11629L, 
11629L, 11630L, 11630L, 11630L, 11630L, 11630L, 11630L, 11630L, 
11630L, 11630L, 11630L, 11630L, 11630L), exp_date_days = c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L
), CustomerName = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ТС", "ТС1"), class = "factor"), 
    DocumentNum = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L
    ), IsPromo = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), CalendarYear = c(2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), diff = 1:33), .Names = c("ItemRelation", 
"exp_date_days", "CustomerName", "DocumentNum", "IsPromo", "CalendarYear", 
"diff"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -33L))
```

## Ispromo has only order 0-1-0!!!

I need for each group `ItemRelation+CustomerName+DocumentNum+CalendarYear` aggregate data  by sum according to the condition.

1. If group by `exp_date_days` has value <=5,then diff column must be  aggregated  by sum  only by 10 zeros which after one category of ispromo. If zeros less than 10, then aggregate by maximum number of zeros.
2. If group by `exp_date_days` has value >5,then diff column must be  aggregate  by sum  only by 15 zeros which after one category of ispromo. If zeros less than 15, then aggregate by maximum number of zeros.

So output in this example

```
ItemRelation    CustomerName    DocumentNum CalendarYear    diff
11629                  ТС          11               2018    126
11630                  ТС          11               2018     285
```

How to do it using dplyr or data.table?

## Edit

```
ItemRelation    exp_date_days   CustomerName    DocumentNum IsPromo CalendarYear    diff
11629   5   ТС  11  0   2018    1
11629   5   ТС  11  0   2018    2
11629   5   ТС  11  0   2018    3
11629   5   ТС  11  0   2018    4
11629   5   ТС  11  0   2018    5
11629   5   ТС  11  0   2018    6
11629   5   ТС  11  0   2018    7
11629   5   ТС  11  0   2018    8
11629   5   ТС  11  0   2018    9
11629   5   ТС  11  0   2018    10
11629   5   ТС  11  0   2018    11
11629   5   ТС  11  0   2018    12
11629   5   ТС  11  1   2018    13
11629   5   ТС  11  1   2018    14
**11629 5   ТС  11  0   2018    15
11629   5   ТС  11  0   2018    16
11629   5   ТС  11  0   2018    17
11629   5   ТС  11  0   2018    18
11629   5   ТС  11  0   2018    19
11629   5   ТС  11  0   2018    20
11629   5   ТС  11  0   2018    21** (sum 126)
```

## edit2

```
ItemRelation    exp_date_days   CustomerName    DocumentNum IsPromo CalendarYear    diff
11630   6   ТС1 11  0   2018    22
11630   6   ТС1 11  1   2018    23
**11630 6   ТС1 11  0   2018    24
11630   6   ТС1 11  0   2018    25
11630   6   ТС1 11  0   2018    26
11630   6   ТС1 11  0   2018    27
11630   6   ТС1 11  0   2018    28
11630   6   ТС1 11  0   2018    29
11630   6   ТС1 11  0   2018    30
11630   6   ТС1 11  0   2018    31
11630   6   ТС1 11  0   2018    32
11630   6   ТС1 11  0   2018    33** (285)
```

Comment: could you specify your conditions a bit more. Perhaps show which rows you sum to get `148` and `285`

Comment: @JakobGepp, i edited post, i mistaked/ not 148, but 126  ** is marked value in diff to aggregate sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do a `filter` after the `group_by` and then get the `sum` of 'diff' column

```
library(dplyr)
mydat %>% 
  group_by(ItemRelation, CustomerName, DocumentNum, CalendarYear) %>% 
  filter(cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(IsPromo == 1) < 0)) == 1) %>% 
  filter(if(all(exp_date_days < 5)) row_number() <= 10 else row_number() <= 15) %>%
  summarise(diff = sum(diff))
# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   ItemRelation, CustomerName, DocumentNum [?]
#  ItemRelation CustomerName DocumentNum CalendarYear  diff
#         <int> <fct>              <int>        <int> <int>
#1        11629 ТС                    11         2018   126
#2        11630 ТС1                   11         2018   285
```

Comment: aren't the conditions missing here? If I understand correctly, then the sum is only calculated over a maximum of 10 or 15 rows depending on `exp_date_days`.

Comment: @JakobGepp  Thanks for pointing that out.  I added one more `filter`

Comment: any question in input i have 14662  groups, but in output i have 14534 groups , where 128 groups?:)

Comment: @D.Joe Could be that some groups don't have any 1 for `IsPromo`?.  Try `mydata %>% group_by(ItemRelation, CustomerName, DocumentNum, CalendarYear) %>% summarise(IsPromo = any(IsPromo== 1)) %>% sum(.$IsPromo)`

Comment: @akrun  i got the error Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables  , So i found 128 groups , and i found pattern 0-1-0-1-0-1... or 0-1-0-1..... it's strange i didn't expect that. So In normal cases, we leave this logic, but in cases like this, we consider this logic only for penultimate zero before  the final first of ispromo. How to do it. Can you edit answer, please?

Comment: @DJoe  From your comment, not able to understand the pattern.  Could you post as a new question.  Thanks